# How to Pass a Form to a Handler in Ratpack unit test

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, ratpack

How do I pass a mocked Form object to a Handler in a unit test? Here's the reference I got so far:

https://ratpack.io/manual/current/testing.html

https://danhyun.github.io/2016-gr8confus-testing-ratpack-apps/

Here is the code for my Handler:

```
void handle(Context context) throws Exception
{
    def queryParams = context.request.queryParams
    context.parse(Form).then {form ->
        String mnemonic = queryParams ['mnemonic']
        String series = queryParams ['series']
        String volume = queryParams ['volume']
        String issue = queryParams ['issue']
        UploadedFile cover = form.file("cover")
    ...
}
```

This is a snippet of the unit test so far:

```
def form = Mock(Form)
form.file(_) >> Mock(UploadedFile)
def result = GroovyRequestFixture.handle(handler) {
        RequestFixture fixture ->
          fixture.uri("/task/node-asset/update-cover-image?"+
          "mnemonic=$mnemonic&series=$mnemonic&volume=$volume&issue=$issue")
          //Pass Mock Form
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a mocked `Form`?

Comment: Ahhh, for the form upload?

Comment: You can use the testHttpClient for your app to post a form ([there's a test here that shows how](https://github.com/ratpack/ratpack/blob/master/ratpack-core/src/test/groovy/ratpack/http/FormHandlingSpec.groovy#L118))